# SetUserData in box2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am writing a game in box2d / cocos2d where things fall from the sky, when they touch the floor or the player they should be removed from the scene.  I have implemented a `ContactListener` as per [Ray Wenderlich's tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/606/how-to-use-box2d-for-just-collision-detection-with-cocos2d-iphone) but the issue with it is that anytime ANYTHING touches anything it gets removed.

What I need is for some way to know which are objects that can be removed.  I see there is a `SetUserData` function in Box2d where I can set data but it will not accept `int`s and seems to accept a class only which seems to add unnecessary complications.

What is the simplest way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out:

```
int yourInt = 2012;
body->SetUserData(@(yourInt));
```

It is using the new Objective-C literal syntax for wrapping the primitive type `int` in an object. The object is wrapped in a `NSNumber`.

`@(yourInt)` is equivalent with saying `[NSNumber numberWithInt:yourInt]`